# How to change the direction arrow in menu's menu item in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I want to change the menu item arrow direction towards downwards side instead of arrow mark pointing towards to right side.

Actually i am having menu , which consists of multiple menu items, i set the menuitem **orientation as horizontal** once i add the menu item to menu, the arrow mark direction pointing towards left hand side by default. **I want to change that arrow mark direction pointing towards downwards side because i will drop down the menu items in vertical manner.**

I used css for menu items.

How to achieve this?? any ideas??

Comment: that arrow is an image or css ? hard to answer without the code. paste your code or make fiddle.

Comment: JSfiddle required. HTML& CSS in your post would also be useful.

Comment: Find the css class of the menu items you want to change cursor for and use a cursor declaration such as http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp although they can behave differently across browsers.

Comment: @Paul Zahra. I don't think he's referring to a cursor at all.

Comment: arrow is css, not an image

Comment: code =<asp:Menu ID="Menu1"  runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="851px" Height="50px" StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="menuHover" DynamicHoverStyle-CssClass="menuHover"  BackColor="#24529c" DynamicMenuStyle-BackColor="#24529c">
  <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuHover"></DynamicHoverStyle>
                                                 <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItem"></DynamicMenuItemStyle>
<DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#24529C" CssClass="dynamicMenu"></DynamicMenuStyle>
                                                    <Items>

Comment: <asp:MenuItem   NavigateUrl="#"  ToolTip="**" Text="**" Value="**">
                                                            <asp:MenuItem ToolTip="**" NavigateUrl="~/**.aspx" Text="**" Value=" ** "></asp:MenuItem>
                                                            <asp:MenuItem ToolTip="**" NavigateUrl="~/**.aspx" Text="**" Value=" ** "></asp:MenuItem>
 </asp:MenuItem>
                                                        <asp:MenuItem ToolTip="**" NavigateUrl="~/**.aspx" Text="Admin Settings" Value="**s"></asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>

Comment: <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menuHover"></StaticHoverStyle>
                                                    <StaticMenuItemStyle ItemSpacing="2px"  CssClass="staticMenuItem"></StaticMenuItemStyle>
                                                    <StaticMenuStyle BorderStyle="Double" />
                                                </asp:Menu>
css class are 

 .menuHover
        {
            color: white;
            background-color: #7693c2;
        }

.dynamicMenuItem
        {
            color: white;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

Comment: .dynamicMenu
        {
          
            position:relative;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;
            z-index:-1;
           padding-left:10px
                    
        }

  .staticMenuItem
        {
            
            border: solid 2px black;
            text-align: center;
            
            font-size: 12pt;
            margin-left: 1px;
            margin-right: 1px;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 1px;
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

Finally i achieved it, by setting  **StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"        DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"** and StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/images/greenarrow.gif"
        DynamicPopOutImageUrl="~/images/greenarrow.gif">

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the image used by Asp.net for the arrow near the menu item
2. Use css to rotate the dropdown image. For example:

```css
.Menu > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > img
 {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```